# Working with dynamic JSON in d3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to use http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033. In the `dndTree.js` in example something like:

```
var t = d3.Json('my.json',function(error,treeData){
//something interesting here
});
```

works real fine with static JSON.But when ever I try to get the data via a WebApi, it stops working.
I tried like :

```
var t = d3.Json($.ajax({url:'../api/MyController'}),function(error,treeData){
//something interesting here
});
```

But this fails.I just need a heads up.
Thanks fellas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `d3.json`, expects a URL, but `$.ajax` returns a jqXHR object. What you actually want is `d3.json('../api/MyController', ...)`.

I recommend to read the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#d3_json).

Comment: giving it a try.I'll let you know.But that's really interesting.